# putting opening file to variable

Tags: python

Putting "source.txt" to variable as this:

```
source = open('/home/user/tmp/python/source.txt','r')
with source as f:
[...]
```

script doesn't run, why? The below script runs:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
with open('/home/user/tmp/python/source.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'www.yahoo.it' in line:
            print (line)
```

Comment: What do you mean `doesn't run`? It's correct and what's the expect output?

Comment: Simply opening a file with `open` doesn't do anything visible. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the complete script you are trying to run?  Are you saying that the second script prints the output you expect, but the first doesn't?  The second script is syntacticly correct and should print any line containing "www.yahoo.it"

Answer (score 3):

The first case does run, but it simply opens a file and binds the file object to variable `source`. It does nothing further with it. If you want to read the content of the file you need to iterate over its lines (as in your second example), or call `source.read()` to read the data.

```
source = open('/home/user/tmp/python/source.txt','r')
for line in source:
    if 'www.yahoo.it' in line:
        print(line)
source.close()
```

The second example from your question is better because it guarantees that the file will be closed upon exit from the context handler (the `with` statement).